# Making a data payload available for multiple requests

Tags: postman

Suppose I have an xml payload.

Request 1 targets API 1:
API 1 is SOAP and as part of the request, should receive this xml payload as CDATA

Request 2 targets API 2:
API 2 is RESTful and as part of the request, should receive this xml payload as a base64 encoded string.

Is there a way to establish this xml payload in a way that allows both requests to reference it?

For example, currently if that xml payload need to change, I would need to modify the corresponding property in the bodies of both Request 1 and Request 2. Instead, I'd like to modify just the xml payload.

Ex:

SOAP:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" >
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <someOperation>
      <someProperty/>
      <someOtherproperty/>
      <etc/>
      <Data><![CDATA[<thatXmlPayload>a few thousand lines</thatXmlPayload]]>
  ...etc...
```

REST:

```
{
    "myProperty" : ...,
    "myOtherProperty" : ...,
    "etc" : ...,
    "content" : thatSameFewThousandLineXmlPayloadButBase64Encoded==
...etc...
```

Comment: You can parse the response and set collection variables that can be used.  You haven't provided any example requests\responses that show what elements are are targeting or might change.   You haven't shown what you have currently tried to resolve this query yourself which in itself will help with context.

Comment: I think there might be a misunderstanding @mikee. Not looking to parse anything. Not worried about other request/responses, just the requests described above. The xml payload itself is a value in this case. It is static and set to a property (a <Data> tag as CDATA in SOAP, a 'content' property as a base64 encoded string in REST). In other words, there are SOAP and REST specifications that are ultimately fronting the same process, both of which requires sending this xml payload as a value in the request. If that xml payload needs to change I'd like to be able to change it in 1 place, not many

Comment: Can you update your question to show screenshots of the two requests, so we can see exactly how each request is currently setup in Postman.  Pretty sure you should be able to use an collection or environment variable and then reference that in each request.  I would need to see the requests to provide more detail on the "how".

Comment: @Mikee, cant screenshot due to sensitive information, but have provided an example

Comment: Create a collection variable with your XML data.  This can be used in the body of the SOAP request using {{variableName}}.  For the REST request, create a pre-request script that retrieves that variable and Base64 encodes it and either sets that as another collection or a local variable that can be used for that request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: No.

Postman is a game changer from a tooling perspective for software engineers.

That being said. It's a pretty dumb piece of 'software'. It's a sexy interface for a basic Request/Response life cycle.

... With the added benefits of the Postman Teams features which are really cool, but not related to this specific question.

So no. Postman isn't going to do the work for you.

Request/Response. You are responsible for defining the Request (including the payload) and Postman will handle the response to make it easy on the eye.

I mean, what you are asking for is probably an extremely good idea, and one that I could personally see people I work with using. But your best approach for this would be to raise a Feature Request with Postman via their preferred method.

But to directly answer your question. No. This is not possible. Just use the good old CTRL + C and CTRL + V.

Unless you're working at scale, this is a mere 2 second inconvenience, not a real problem.